# Como fazer logout no Django?

Tags: python, django-2.0

Eu consegui criar e logar um usuário no sistema, mas o logout não funciona e eu não entendo o motivo.

**View**:

```
def logout_view(request):

     logout(request)
     return redirect('home')
```

**Arquivo html que chama a url que por sua vez chama a view:**

```
<div class="dropdown-menu ">

<a class="dropdown-item " href="#">Perfil</a>
<div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>

</div>
```

**Url**:

```
path('home.html',views.logout_view,name='logout')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Login no VIEWS

```
def pag_login(request):
if request.user.id:
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/index')
if request.POST:
    usuario = request.POST.get('usuario')
    senha = request.POST.get('senha')
    u = authenticate(username=usuario, password=senha)
    if u is not None:
        if u.is_active:
            login(request, u)
            next = request.GET.get('next')
            if next:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/index')
        else:
            erro = 'Usuário inativo'
    else:
        erro = "Usuário ou senha inválido"
return render(request, 'login.html', locals())
```

Sair no VIEWS

```
@login_required
def sair(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/login')
```

URL

```
path('deslogar', sair), //você pode adequar isso com seu cod.
```

Deslogar no HTML

```
<a href="deslogar">Sair</a>
```

Comment: Funcionou agora, valeu!!

Comment: Okay, Disponha.